# "... we should have got to Paris" vs. "... we should be in Paris"

Tags: grammar, tenses, subjunctive-mood, got-gotten

I'm confused by the two sentences below. Are they both subjunctive mood?

Both of them use "by now", but one uses "should be" and another uses "should have done" to describe action doesn't happen. What're the differences between the two usages?

> By now I should be in Paris, if I'd caught my train.
> The train must be running late; we should have got to Paris by now.

Comment: "get to" means "arrive", "be" means to be located in a place. This is about the different meanings of different verbs.

Answer (score 1):

*Modern English Usage* has this entry on *if structures* (p258):

> After *I* and *we*, *should* can be used with the same meaning as
> *would*. (*Would* is more common in modern English; *should* is rare in AmE.)

So, *"By now I would be in Paris, if I'd caught my train"* sounds more natural to the modern ear than *"By now I should be in Paris, if I'd caught my train*".

In the second sentence *"The train must be running late; we should have got to Paris by now*",  *should* can be replaced by *ought to* with the same meaning.

*Modern English Usage* has this entry on *ought* (p403):

> **3 deduction: He ought to be here soon**
> We can also use *ought* (like *should*) to say or conclude that
> something is probable (because it is logical or normal).

In this case, the deduction is that the train is running late because we are not yet in Paris.

Neither sentence is in the subjunctive mood as understood by modern grammarians.

Comment: got here is British for: By now we should have gotten to Paris. AmE